# Fill in numpy array upto position based on another array

Tags: python, numpy

```
    import numpy as np
    arr_keys = np.array(np.mat('2 3 1 0; 3 3 3 1'))
    arr_rand1 = np.random.rand(2, 4)
    arr_rand2 = np.random.rand(2, 4)

    arr_final = np.zeros((5, 2, 4))
```

I want to create a numpy array called arr_final of shape (100, 2, 4) where 100 can be thought to correspond to time and 2, 4 are number of rows and columns respectively
To fill `arr_final`, I want to use the following logic:

1. For each grid cell in `arr_final`, look up value in corresponding position in `arr_keys`, lets call it `val_alpha`
2. Fill `arr_final` using values from `arr_rand1` upto the `val_alpha` position, and using values from `arr_rand2` after that

This can be done using a for loop but is there a more pythonic solution?

--EDIT:

Here's the for loop soln:

```
for (i, j, k), value in np.ndenumerate(arr_final):
    val_alpha = arr_keys[j][k]
    arr_final[:val_alpha, j, k] = arr_rand1[j, k]
    arr_final[val_alpha:, j, k] = arr_rand2[j, k]
```

Comment: Can you show the loopy solution just so that we understand the problem better and also use it verify?

Comment: Could you add your for-loop solution to your post? That would make it more clear what end result exactly you're looking to achieve.

Comment: thanks, added the for loop based soln

Comment: updated it again to correct a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could make use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `boolean-indexing/masking` -

```
L = 5 # length of output array
mask = arr_keys > np.arange(L)[:,None,None]
arr_final_out = np.where(mask,arr_rand1,arr_rand2)
```